# How to add meta slider lite or other slider to main page header in pinboard theme

Tags: shortcode, slideshow

Slider is created using Meta Slider Lite v2.2.1.

Meta Slider shows it usage as

```
Shortcode 

[metaslider id=449]

Template Include 

<?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=449]"); ?>
```

Pinboard theme is used.
Text module is added to its header element.
Text element contains

```
[metaslider id=449]
<?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=449]"); ?>
```

slider does not appear. View source shows that

```
[metaslider id=449]
<?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=449]"); ?>
```

are rendered literally.

How to show slider in header ?

Comment: best thing is to ask the theme developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect *Meta Slider Lite v2.2.1* is a plugin and that the instructions are telling you to either use a shortcode in the WordPress editor or the PHP code in a template file. They are not likely to be telling you to use both at the same time.

I don't know what a *text module* is, but I suspect it is a modified text widget. By default, text widgets do not expand shortcodes or a run PHP code.

Check the Pinboard documentation (or with their support) to find a *module* that will expand shortcode or run PHP code.

Comment: If you don't know so many things why do you answer at all? The idea here is to try to provide a definitive answer not guesses....

Comment: You're right. I was being lazy.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using your answer I was able to find solution. I upvoted answer to compensate Marks downvote.

Answer (score 0):

To include it in your theme eg: header.php you use the php echo one. To include it on a page you use the part in the square brackets, including brackets and paste it into the WYSIWYG editor

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [don't do_shortcode](https://kovshenin.com/2013/dont-do_shortcode/) as its not the most efficient method.

Use the sliders function in the header.php file with a [`conditional tag`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) like this example where you'll need to swap out the slider function with the one that works with your plugin:

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() && function_exists( "easingsliderlite" ) ) { easingsliderlite(); } ?>
```

You can move the above code around in the header file to change the position of the slider on the front end.